# Hibernate+spring Exception: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Пытаюсь подружить Hibernate и spring, но никак не могу победить... При компиляции возникает ошибка, подскажите что можно сделать...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:356)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:323)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:637)
    at springPackage.config.RoleStorage.add(RoleStorage.java:30)
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Вот классы:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Component
public class Personx {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    public Personx(){

    }

    public Personx(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class RoleStorage implements RoleDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RoleStorage(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Personx> values() {
        return (List<Personx>) this.hibernateTemplate.find("FROM Personx");
    }

    @Override
    public int add(Personx user) {
        return (int) this.hibernateTemplate.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(Personx user) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {

    }

    @Override
    public Personx get(int id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Personx findByLogin(String login) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int generateId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

мэйн:

```
import springPackage.config.RoleStorage;
import springPackage.models.Personx;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

        RoleStorage storage = applicationContext.getBean(RoleStorage.class);
        storage.add(new Personx("nanasdn"));

    }
}
```

applicationconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>springPackage.models.Personx</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test4" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>

    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="springPackage"/>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.litvinov.h</groupId>
    <artifactId>hiber5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <version.spring>4.3.2.RELEASE</version.spring>
        <version.hibernate>5.1.0.Final</version.hibernate>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: тебе же написали
`remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.`
Ну и создавать бин из Entity это бред какой-то. Что ты хочешь с этим сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго ломал голову, очень много эксепшенов ловил после этого. Решился вопрос добавлением интерфейса для классов для работы транзакций... Все приходит с опытом...